# How can I use pthread on apache2?

Tags: docker, pthreads, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.0

I need to use PHP-FPM with pthread in apache2, to improve performance in a Prestashop 1.6 store, runing in Ubuntu 16.04.

I have done many intents. These are the lasts two tests:

1) I was able to run parallel PHP code using pthread in XAMP v3.2.1, but it restarts the apache server. I think this has something to do with the fact that in XAMP apache already uses worker threads. (I have a question about this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129449/is-apache2-using-threads-or-process-in-ubuntu-18-04)

2) I compilled PHP 7.0.33, following this tutorial: https://blog.programster.org/install-php-7-0-with-pthreads-on-ubuntu-16.04 I used a docker container with a base of Ubuntu 16.04, to avoid dependencies problems and versions error. However, I get the following error in my browser when I access to a PHP script with pthread code:  **Fatal error: Class 'Threaded' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 5**
This script is the same as the one in the tutorial, where pthread is tested from CLI.

After all this I have noticed that pthread is only for CLI. This is explained in the following links: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/748001/the-apache2handler-sapi-is-not-supported-by-pthreads
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

So my questions are:

1) Is there any way to use Pthread in PHP-FPM with apache ?

2) Is there any alternative to improve speed in PHP ? (I already tried with: APC and APCU.)

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: You should first diagnose the problem. Where is the bottle neck now? Threads are probably not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not directly related to pthread however, as of Apr 2019, rather than using Apache 2, to get the best performance for your PrestaShop store,

**I'd recommend the following:**

- Nginx 1.16
- PHP FPM 7.3 (huge performance boost vs 7.0), configured with a dedicated pool
- MariaDB 10.3 (optional: build a master/slave setup with two servers)

**Then:**

- Enable Gzip
- Enable cache for static content and/or use a CDN to serve these files
- Enable CCC (minify/compress/cache) in the PrestaShop admin panel

**And finally:**

- Enable the PHP Zend Opcache and use these settings (in production only):

  `[opcache]
  zend_extension=php_opcache.so
  opcache.enable=1
  opcache.enable_cli=1
  opcache.memory_consumption=1024
  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
  opcache.max_accelerated_files=16229
  opcache.validate_timestamps=0
  opcache.revalidate_freq=0
  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
  opcache.save_comments=0
  opcache.enable_file_override=1
  opcache.log_verbosity_level=0
  opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks=0
  opcache.validate_permission=0
  opcache.validate_root=0`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will analize your proposition.

Comment: I think that is a threat Bruno.

Comment: @ficuscr A threat?

Comment: Bad joke about the typo in the comment. Sorry.

Comment: The application can not be fully migrated to the configuration that you proposed, because of specific compatibility issues. However, I appreciate your sugestions @Bruno Leveque.